# Why is this making a blank Bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3

I run through a few loops to build out a 32 x 32 block
In my real example the colors vary but in testing, even simplified I am getting nowhere

```
var tempWidth:int = currentTileSel.width;
            var tempHeight:int = currentTileSel.height;
            var newbit:Bitmap = null;
            var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(tempWidth, tempHeight,true,0x000000);
            var drawCount:int = 0;

            for(var i:int = 0; i< tempHeight; i++)
            {                       
                for(var j:int = 0; j < tempWidth; j++)
                {
                    var setColor:uint = pixelArray[drawCount].colorfill;
                    myBitmapData.setPixel32(j,i,0x000000);

                    drawCount++;
                }
            }
            ///*
            currentTileSel.graphics.clear();
            currentTileSel.graphics.lineStyle(.25,0xCCCCCC,.5,false);
            currentTileSel.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmapData);
            currentTileSel.graphics.drawRect(0,0,tempWidth,tempHeight);
            currentTileSel.graphics.endFill();
            currentTileSel.bitmapHolder = myBitmapData;
            //*/
            newbit = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
            gridLoader.addChild(newbit);
```

I would think this would produce a black bitmap pixel by pixel, but I get nothing on the bitmapFill and nothing when I add it to the screen as a bitmap.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
myBitmapData.setPixel32(j,i,0x000000);
```

Here, you are setting the transparency to 0.
Try:

```
myBitmapData.setPixel32(j,i,0xFF000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing transparent black pixels. Instead of 0x000000 it should be 0xff000000.

```
myBitmapData.setPixel32(j,i,0xff000000);
```

or use setPixel(x, y, color);